# What's the best way to teach a 5yr old to play chess?

Tags: video-games

My son figured out checkers a few months ago..but got bored playing when he realized chess existed and that there are a lot more variety of players and movements.

He also loves video games. Is there an app or video that teaches chess in a really fun way? i found 99% of the youtube videos are sleep inducers for 5yr olds. We did discover Battle Chess which he was really into..but its way too violent. I have no idea what those creators were thinking at the time.

Comment: This may or may not be the "best" way, but I imagine it might be a lot of fun for a 5 year old: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Chess_in_Christchurch,_New_Zealand.jpg

Comment: There is a chess.se that might have some ideas. Perusing variety or novelty is likely a path that leads away from chess though.

Comment: It is not at all clear to me that it is natural for a 5 year old to progress from "Gee, look at all the pieces" to "I want to play chess".

Comment: Find someone who likes to play chess with him.  At my brother in law's wedding I was introduced to my 5 year old second nephew twice removed (or something along that line) who was quite the chess player. The two of us spent most of the reception party huddled over one of the chessboards at the B&B. He was not a ranked player by any means, and I am no longer the chess player I used to be, but he still won about one game in three once I showed him castling.

Comment: Why not just teach him yourself?

Comment: i ended up having him watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KlTEQZ5Sy4E in the morning..

and last night he really didnt want to go to bed.. and i said Ok 'the only way you get to stay up another 15min, is if we play our first game"

i also started the game without the knight ( since his moves are still a bit too complex for him to memorize along with all the other pieces he has too ) and without half the pawns. 

he blew my mind. and managed to stay alive for 30min.

Comment: He might also enjoy go.  My son got interested in Go when we watched "hikaru no go" (roughly "Johnny plays Go") together.  You can build a simple go board with cardboard and a couple of sharpies.

Comment: Once he knows how the pieces move,  show him the classical openings. Little by little he will become a stronger player as long as he remains interested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to teach the very basics, such as pieces movement, you can play simplified chess variants, such as only pawns, knights game, etc.

After the very basics, one approach is to play easy endgames: that should help to make it clear from the outset that chess is not about moving your pieces around, but to try to checkmate the opponent. About *checkmate*, though, you might as well skip it for now and let the games end by the *capture* of the king as a further simplification.

The next step is probably to make her notice there are less and more powerful pieces. Or you could be to try to get them to realize there are some very bad and some very good openings, or just do some free play, giving tips here and there. The best approach will strongly depend on the individual child. There's some more specific advice [in this forum thread](https://www.chess.com/forum/view/scholastic-chess/teaching-chess-to-kids) and in [this answer](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/4987/shorter-game-for-play-with-kids). BTW, at [Chess SE](https://chess.stackexchange.com/) you can probably find chess instructors who'll be able to give qualified advice.

When the kid becomes interested enough, taking part in a chess club, association or similar would be of great help.

Lastly, if you'd like this kind of tool, [this site](https://www.chesskid.com/learn-how-to-play-chess) looks promising and I've seen it recommended.